# should the Swift Model object make calls to API?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am wondering if I am following the MVC architectural pattern, in my Model class can I make a call to the API?

i.e.

```
class DataModel {
    var data = "Some data that's a string"
    func getAPIData(){
       self.data = self.NetworkFunctionsClass.MakeAPICallFunction()
    }
}
```

I am not directly making a function in my Model class

Is this allowed? Or am I violating the Model rule by introducing some actions rather than storing data?

Comment: Yes , I think parsing api data or using that data in model should work as long as it is not connected with interface or how that api data is to be presented is defined in the model. Please checkout [Apple's MVC documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html)

Comment: Tip: If you project is very large you could try VIPER.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in my Model class can I make a call to the API?

There is nothing limits you from being able to do so, but usually that's *not* expected. From the traditional perspective for the standard MVC, the *Controller* layer is the responsible for such a task.

However, for the purpose of avoiding the "Massive View Controller" problem, you could apply the "MVC-N" approach. Actually, it nothing but a standard MVC + Networking client! Which leads to:

- Avoiding duplicating the networking logic in each view controller.
- Making the view controllers to be less "massive".

So, it goes as:

The Networking handles -obviously- the API requests, deserializing response (as models) and pass it to the view controller; Therefore the controller should *not* know about the models. The communication between the Networking and the Controllers layer is -usually- achieved by *closures*, and sometimes you might need to follow the approach of delegates.

Back to your case, you will be refine the code as (pseudo-code):

```
class DataModel {
    var data = "Some data that's a string"
}

// separating the networking logic in another class:
class Networking {
    func getAPIData(url: URL, parameters: [String: Any], response: @escaping (_ dataModel: DataModel) -> Void) {
        // ...

        // here, you should pass the returned data model:
        response(DataModel())
    }
}
```

And, in the view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // somewhere in the view controller, you could pass it as:
        Networking().getAPIData(url: ..., parameters: ...) { data in
            // here, you can access `data`...
        }
    }
}
```

Certainly, the logic is also applicable for any specified tasks functionality -and not only networking-, such as fetching the device photos (accessing system resources) or writing and reading data from/into the disk.

Comment: Thanks! The explanation was very clear and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

In a data model class, I usually have inits that can create an instance of the model class from whatever an API delivers; if I had to use two APIs I would have two init methods. And of course methods that create whatever data the API expects if I'm sending data model instances to the API.

So if I had one API delivering the data as JSON, and another API delivering the data as XML using completely different names (I usually can't control naming in the API), I'd have two inits taking JSON or XML as parameters.

Doing the network access is a step too far in my opinion. Especially since I often use APIs containing data that will be represented by different model objects. Like a "library" API that could return a book, a CD, or a DVD and the call should produce one of three different model classes. In that situation you might not have an API call "give me a book", only "give me an item in the library" which returns an instance that could belong to one of several model classes.